# How to find npm configuration error or reset npm from scratch?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have created a test project folder that includes a very simple package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

When running `npm install` inside the project folder though, it installs a LOT of packages. Where do all these come from? Is there some error in an npm configuration somewhere?

This is inside my node_modules folder now:

```
amdefine
ansi-green
ansi-regex
ansi-styles
ansi-wrap
anymatch
arr-diff
arr-flatten
array-uniq
array-unique
arrify
asn1
assert-plus
async
async-each
aws-sign2
babel-cli
babel-code-frame
babel-core
babel-generator
babel-helpers
babel-messages
babel-polyfill
babel-regenerator-runtime
babel-register
babel-runtime
babel-template
babel-traverse
babel-types
babylon
balanced-match
bin-version
bin-version-check
binary-extensions
bl
boom
brace-expansion
braces
builtin-modules
camelcase
camelcase-keys
caseless
chalk
chokidar
combined-stream
commander
concat-map
convert-source-map
core-js
core-util-is
cryptiles
dashdash
debug
delayed-stream
detect-indent
ecc-jsbn
error-ex
escape-string-regexp
esutils
expand-brackets
expand-range
extend
extglob
extsprintf
filename-regex
fill-range
find-up
find-versions
for-in
for-own
forever-agent
form-data
fs-readdir-recursive
fsevents
generate-function
generate-object-property
get-stdin
glob
glob-base
glob-parent
globals
graceful-fs
graceful-readlink
har-validator
has-ansi
hawk
hoek
home-or-tmp
hosted-git-info
http-signature
indent-string
inflight
inherits
invariant
is-arrayish
is-binary-path
is-buffer
is-builtin-module
is-dotfile
is-equal-shallow
is-extendable
is-extglob
is-finite
is-glob
is-integer
is-my-json-valid
is-number
is-primitive
is-property
is-typedarray
is-utf8
isarray
isobject
isstream
jodid25519
js-tokens
jsbn
json-schema
json-stringify-safe
json5
jsonpointer
jsprim
kind-of
left-pad
line-numbers
load-json-file
lodash
log-symbols
loose-envify
loud-rejection
map-obj
meow
micromatch
mime-db
mime-types
minimatch
minimist
mkdirp
ms
nan
node-uuid
normalize-package-data
normalize-path
number-is-nan
oauth-sign
object-assign
object.omit
once
os-tmpdir
output-file-sync
parse-glob
parse-json
path-exists
path-is-absolute
path-type
pify
pinkie
pinkie-promise
preserve
private
process-nextick-args
qs
randomatic
read-pkg
read-pkg-up
readable-stream
readdirp
redent
regex-cache
repeat-element
repeat-string
repeating
request
semver
semver-regex
semver-truncate
shebang-regex
signal-exit
slash
sntp
source-map
source-map-support
spdx-correct
spdx-exceptions
spdx-expression-parse
spdx-license-ids
sshpk
string_decoder
stringstream
strip-ansi
strip-bom
strip-indent
success-symbol
supports-color
to-fast-properties
tough-cookie
trim-newlines
trim-right
tunnel-agent
tweetnacl
user-home
util-deprecate
v8flags
validate-npm-package-license
verror
wrappy
xtend
```

If I botched my npm configuration somehow, what is the best way to reset it? Can I just uninstall node/npm and everything with it?

Comment: Have you used these modules in anther project or are they just coming seemingly randomly?

Comment: Most of them don't seem familiar, but it's possible that I downloaded/  installed them in a tutorial project ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

you probably made the command

> npm install

in the same folder when you created another files.

And babel-cli alone has 20 dependencies:
v8flags, source-map, slash, request, path-is-absolute, path-exists, output-file-sync, log-symbols, lodash, glob, fs-readdir-recursive, convert-source-map, commander, chokidar, chalk, bin-version-check, babel-runtime, babel-polyfill, babel-register, babel-core

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise that. But even if all these packages belong to babel then still... the babel CLI command is not working...

Comment: @Kokodoko ```babel-cli``` is a ```cli``` program, which means it should be in path to be able to run in. Specify manual path, or install globally ```npm install -g babel-cli```

Comment: If you install a package locally, without -g switch you can access it as `node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that! The Babel page specifically mentions NOT to install it globally since you might need different Babel versions for each project.